# Querying the Results of a select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I am new to SQL and am trying to pull some data from a database.

I have two tables one called 'tblorders' and the other 'tblorderitems', to which I want to add up the number of items ordered by the team.

This is the query I created:

```
SELECT fldcustomerid, fldname, fldcontactname, fldemail, SUM(fldqtyorder) as QtyOrdered
FROM tblorders AS A
INNER JOIN tblorderitems AS B ON A.fldorderid = B.fldorderid
WHERE fldstockcode LIKE 'TO%' AND fldorderdate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
AND fldemail LIKE '%@%' AND fldqtyorder>=30
GROUP BY fldname, fldcustomerid, fldcontactname, fldemail
ORDER BY QtyOrdered DESC
```

I expect it to add up the number of items from the 'fldqtyorder' column and then filter the results so that only results with over 30 items will show.

For Example the intial table would be:

```
fldname:     fldqtyorder:     fldcontactname:     fldemail:
TeamFC            24          Fred Jones          email@email1.com
FootyFC           1           Steve Low           Steeve@footy.com
TeamFC            16          James Wild          James@bt.com
Palm FC           33          Phil Bate           PBate@blah.com
```

The final results should be as followed:

```
fldname:     fldtotalqtyorder:     fldcontactname:     fldemail:
TeamFC               40            Fred Jones          email@email1.com 
Palm FC              33            Phil Bate           PBate@blah.com
```

Comment: use a having fldqtyorder>-30

Comment: Answering the subject line only, `select something from (select statement goes here) derivedTable where etc`

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
SELECT fldcustomerid, fldname, fldcontactname, fldemail, SUM(fldqtyorder) as QtyOrdered
FROM tblorders AS A
INNER JOIN tblorderitems AS B ON A.fldorderid = B.fldorderid
WHERE fldstockcode LIKE 'TO%' AND fldorderdate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
AND fldemail LIKE '%@%'
GROUP BY fldname
HAVING QtyOrdered >= 30
ORDER BY QtyOrdered DESC
```

You have different fldcontactnames for the same fldname, so it will randomly choose one for your output. Same with fldemail and fldcustomerid. But otherwise, the output should be what you are looking for.

You can't just throw the extra fields into the group by clause, because that breaks apart the group by each row that has a unique combination of those fields. If you want the rows to collapse into one row whenever they have the same fldname, then ONLY fldname can be in the group by clause.

Comment: I don't believe that will execute, since you select fields that are not in the group by clause and are not aggregates.

Comment: It is allowed in Mysql, it just chooses a value arbitrarily, as I tried to explain above. Probably not what the OP really wants, but that does match the given output. A more sensible query should just skip the fields that are not properly aggregated, i.e. fldcustomerid, fldcontactname, and fldemail. But that is not how the question was asked.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that was the case in MySQL. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: I have tried the following to just get the name of the team, which is returning the amount of results as I expected, however, how do i show the email that corresponds with that team without affecting the results?

Comment: 'code' SELECT DISTINCT fldname as ClubName
FROM tblorders AS A
INNER JOIN tblorderitems AS B ON A.fldorderid = B.fldorderid
WHERE fldstockcode LIKE 'TO%' AND fldorderdate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
GROUP BY fldname, fldemail
HAVING SUM(fldqtyorder)>30 
ORDER BY ClubName ASC 'code'

Comment: You've got multiple emails for the same team, so if you put fldemail in the select clause, it will give you one of them. You don't need the "DISTINCT" here since the group by already makes each row distinct with respect to the fldname. In other words, it does nothing.

Comment: If you instead want the totals for each distinct email address, you can add fldemail to the select clause and the group by clause. It effectively subdivides your group into each distinct email.

Answer (score 0):

This is an order of operation question.

At the time the where clause is evaluated its only on single record by record.  By moving the evaluation of the sum to the having clause, the engine will evaluate the aggregate and return only those >= 30.

Put simply remove the >=30 from the where and put it in a having (no subquery needed)

```
SELECT fldcustomerid
     , fldname
     , fldcontactname
     , fldemail
     , SUM(fldqtyorder) as QtyOrdered
FROM tblorders AS A
INNER JOIN tblorderitems AS B 
  ON A.fldorderid = B.fldorderid
WHERE fldstockcode LIKE 'TO%' 
  AND fldorderdate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
  AND fldemail LIKE '%@%' 
GROUP BY fldname, fldcustomerid, fldcontactname, fldemail
HAVING sum(fldqtyorder)>=30
ORDER BY QtyOrdered DESC
```